# Proving two graphs are isomorphic in polynomial time - Bondy/Murty - Graph Theory Page 6

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to do the below problem:

[image]

Now I can't see how one does this. I know you can explicitly show the bijections, but I can't see an easy way to do this, since it is $3\text{-regular}$.

I read somewhere that this can't be done in polynomial time, and can only be done by brute force. Is this true?

Comment: Trial and error looks like it should work rather quickly, especially if you focus on finding the obvious structures of the left-hand graph in the right. Have you not tried it yet?

Comment: @Hurkyl Well it might sound silly, but I didn't have a pencil, so I  tried to do it visually, this failed for over ten minutes, and then I considered the fact that I may get much larger graphs, so perhaps a general method would be better to know. Is there no theorem that proves this based on length of inner cycles etc?

Comment: For future reference, if you post a question with a figure, it would be well to label the points in the figure, to make it easier for us answerers to write our answers.

Comment: @bof Sorry, I thought perhaps there might be a trick to order of labeling, but I will do this in future. Thank you

Comment: See the Wikipedia link I added to my answer. No polynomial time algorithm is known, but it's an open problem whether one exists.

Comment: @Bof Thanks again bof, I'll find one ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unsolved problem whether [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) can be decided in polynomial time. That's irrelevant here, because "polynomial time" is about large problems and asymptotics, and your problem is about a fixed pair of very small graphs.

It took me about a minute to find an isomorphism by trial. First, I looked at the big pentagon on the left, and labeled the vertices cyclically 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Then I found a 5-cycle over on the right, and labeled the vertices there 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Then I took the third neighbor of vertex 1 on the left and labeled it 6, and did the same on the right. And so on. Everything worked without a hitch, no backtracking needed.

What did you try?

Comment: The $5$ cycle idea is great. I see there are many, but they are linked

Comment: It works without a hitch because the graph has a lot of symmetries (self isomorphisms). I think you could identify any 5-cycle with any other (as a start) and it will work.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, that's easy to see if you regard it (the Petersen graph) as the complement of the line graph of $K_5$.